# Several job titles for the same employer in moderncv

Tags: moderncv, cv

I was wondering how can I tweak `moderncv` to create entries for multiple job titles with the same employer.

I am basically interested in mimicking approach 2 that is explained [here](http://career-advice.monster.com/resumes-cover-letters/resume-writing-tips/one-employer-multiple-jobs-resume/article.aspx) using the classic theme if possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

I have been experimenting, and the following is a MWE example as suggested:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}        

\firstname{FirstName}
\familyname{LastName}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Recent Experience}

\cventry{Jan 2010 -- Current}
        {Company}
        {City}
        {Country}
        {}
        {}

\cventry{Jan 2011 -- Current}
    {Senior Position}
    {}
    {}
    {}
    {
      Roles and responsibilities
    }

\cventry{Jan 2010 -- Jan 2011}
    {Associate Position}
    {}
    {}
    {}
    {
      Roles and responsibilities
    }
\end{document}
```

Please note that it requires aesthetic improvements.

Comment: You would need to write a new style for what you seem to want (put the employer on a separate line, with each role below). But IMHO, that won't get you an attractive resume; if you've been promoted several times, potential employers will care mainly about 2 things: your latest responsibilities and your promotion path/speed. The best way to show this, is to stack your roles with dates and locations, and then provide a combined paragraph detailing your responsibilities, focussing on the most impressive (hence usually latest) ones.

Comment: @Xavier could you please point me towards a template that utilises `moderncv` that implements your suggestion. 
Edit:
I came up with the following but it doesn't feel right:

    \cventry{Jan 2011 -- Current}
        {Senior Position}
        {Company}
        {City}
        {Country}
        {
        }

    \cventry{Jan 2010 -- Jan 2011}
        {Associate Position}
        {Company}
        {City}
        {Country}
        {
        }

    \cventry{}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {
             details for tasks
            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in my comment, I would rather stack the positions with dates and locations, and provide a combined paragraph detailing your responsibilities below:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Recent Experience}
\cventry{2011--current}{Senior Position}{Company}{City}{}{}
\cventry{2010--2011}   {Junior Position}{Company}{City}{}{%
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Responsibility 1
    \item Responsibility 2
  \end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the template. However, in order to satisfy my curiosity, could you please elaborate on how I would write a new style that implements the original approach. I just want to compare the two approaches, if possible.

Comment: If you want to write a new style (based on the `classic` style), just copy the file `moderncvstyleclassic.sty` and rename the copy `moderncvstylecustom.sty`. Edit the file the way you want (look for example for the definition of `\cventry` and reimplement it) and load your custom style with `\moderncvstyle{custom}` in your resume file.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can add multiple roles within the same company by leaving the company name and location empty for earlier positions/cventries.

Ref: https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/453d6947cabe45ece5631456e1d0fc905b9d4998/moderncvbodyiii.sty#L168